# Which resources are not renewable?

Tags: dont-starve

Which resources can't be gotten back after you farm them in Don't Starve?  I know that if you dig up grass, a berry bush, or sapling, you can replant them in another spot.  However, if you put them in the research machine, are they totally gone for good or do they respawn somewhere else on the map?  If not, does that mean that there is a limited amount of stone and gold that you can get per map?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a handy list of the current known resources and their availability:

## Renewable

- **Grass**
- **Twigs**
- **Reeds**
- **Berries:** infinitely renewable in the wild.  If dug up and replanted, renewable but must be fertilized after every five berry harvests.
- **Manure:** infinitely available, as long as you have a herd of beefalo near you, or a pigmen village (feed them vegetables or flower petals), or a koalefant.
- **Beefalos:** renewable if a herd exists. Calves are born every autumn which add to the herd. Kill the last beefalo and it becomes extinct.
- **Pigmen:** generated indefinitely from their village or from pig houses.  If the pig in a house is killed, the house generates a new pig in four days.
- **Wood:** renewable. Trees can be planted back from pine cones, unless you destroy the pine cones or burn the forest. Pro tip: dig up the tree stump to get one more log.
- **Gold:** renewable. Gold from gold-veined boulders don't respawn, *but* if you find a Pig King you can feed him meat (a renewable resource) or eggs (feed a bird in a cage monster meat to get them, or steal them from pengulls) or give him trinkets to get gold nuggets in return. Cave quakes can drop gold.
- **Flowers:** renewable. Flowers spawn butterflies which, when caught with a bug net and planted, yield more flowers
- **Spiders:** putting them in the resources because of the Silk. The nests generate new spiders when you kill them, up to their current limit (it should be 6 for the small nest, 9 for the medium and 12 for the big).  If you kill all the spiders in a nest, they'll regenerate over time.  If you destroy a tier 1 or 2 spider nest, you get spider silk but the nest is gone for good.  But if you destroy a tier 3 spider nest (it has three lumps of web), you get six spider silk and one spider egg that can be planted to create a new spider nest.  (The only way to increase the number of spider nests is to let a tier 3 nest become a Spider Queen; she leaves behind a tier 1 nest, walks around for a day or two, and then becomes another tier 1 nest.)
- **Rabbits:** they're regenerated as long as their holes are intact; if you dig up the hole, a rabbit comes out, but the hole is permanently destroyed
- **Turkeys:** they're *vermin* and they're there to gobble on your berries! Randomly generated in any bush, you don't have to worry about their quantity.
- **Flint:** Those that you pick up don't respawn anywhere else on the surface. They drop in caves on earthquakes;
- **Rocks:** Destroying a boulder or a stalagmite yields rocks, flint and occasionally gold, but boulders don't respawn. They drop in caves on earthquakes;
- **Frogs:** continuously generated from ponds.  Frog Legs are also left when a Merm is killed.
- **Fish:** continuously generated from ponds.  Fish are also left behind when a Merm is killed.
- **Bees:** continuously generated by beehives or bee boxes, up to a maximum of four per hive/box.
- **All Farmable crops**: your farms keep generating crops, needing the occasional (renewable) manure to fertilise the farm.
- **Honey**: You can get honey by killing bees (the bees will renew); or by creating bee boxes and then harvesting them periodically.  (You can also get honey from destroying a beehive, but beehives don't appear to be renewable.)
- **Mushrooms**: They come back in a few days as long as you pick them.  If you dig one, you'll get two at once but they'll never appear there again.

## Not renewable

- **Saplings** - once they're gone (e.g. by being burned), they're gone.  You can replant them anywhere, though.
- **Berry Bushes** - likewise.  If you dig up a berry bush, you'll need to fertilize it when you plant it, and again periodically, to keep it producing berries.
- **Grass Tufts** - likewise.  If you dig up a grass tuft, you'll need to fertilize it when you plant it, and again periodically, to keep it producing grass.
- **Rabbit Holes** - if you dig one up, it's gone forever
- **Mushroom locations** - if you dig one up, it's gone forever
- **Honeycomb** - you get one if you destroy a beehive, and you can use it to create a bee box.  But it appears that the number of beehives you start with is all you get.  You can also get honeycombs from killer bee hives.

As you can see, the list is still a work in progress, since I'm trying to discover everything on my own. I'll try to keep this updated every time I find something new. Keep in mind anyway that new features are constantly added to Don't Starve, so these information is not fixed and still likely to be changed from time to time.

Comment: Great list.  One thing that I did find out is that you can get additional gold by trading the Pig King stuff you find in graves.  He throws out about 4 nuggets.  I don't know if the stuff in graves respawns though.  If it does, then gold can be considered unlimited at this point.

Comment: @zero298 I didn't put the Pig King in the list because I've never found him. From what I've heard anyway you can give him also meat for gold, but I still have to verify this. The content of the graves doesn't respawn anyway, so no endless gold, sorry :P

Comment: Carrots can be grown in farm plots. Since everything that goes into a farm plot is renewable, they are too.

Comment: I'm wondering if we don't need a third classification -- wood for example. You can regrow trees as long as you chop them down, but if you run out of flint you can no longer chop them down. Unless I'm missing a way to get wood, your wood supply is limited by your access to flint. Are other things like this, or is wood a special case?

Comment: @Peter you don't have any control on what's going to grow on your farm plot. You simply put in the seeds and wait. Regarding wood: it's not limited by flint. The Luxury Axe, Regal Shovel and Opulent Pickaxe are made with just twigs and gold. Gold is rare, but the golden tools will last you ~4x the normal tools.

Comment: So I guess the sustainability of wood depends on whether or not you can get gold sustainably. If you can convert meat to gold per your comment, it would be renewable. If gold isn't renewable, as per your post, wood would not be.

Comment: @Peter Got to Klei forums to find out more, it looks like you [can feed meat to the Pig King in exchange of gold](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?266-King-of-the-Pigs-what-does-he-do). Updated the answer with the new informations.

Comment: afaik moleworms can dig up gold, so maybe renewable?

Answer (score 1):

The only things in the game that aren't renewable including animals and objects are:  ghosts, swamp monsters, frogs, rocks,and flint. The only thing I don't know is whether or not hounds appear indefinitely.